# I use setState in Yii but i also get Property "CWebUser.depId" is not defined

Tags: yii, setstate

i want to return the value dep_id from table user to use it so setState is supposed to return it like (Yii::app()->user->depId) but when i use it i get -- "CWebUser.depId" is not defined. i searched and i dont know what to do and i need a quick answer this is my 
example:

```
private $_id;
//private $_dep_id;
public function authenticate()
{
    $user=User::model()->find('LOWER(username)=?',array(strtolower($this->username)));
    if($user===null)
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_USERNAME_INVALID;
    else if(!$user->validatePassword($this->password))
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_PASSWORD_INVALID;
    else
    {
        $this->_id=$user->id;
        $this->setState('depId',$user->dep_id);            
        $this->username=$user->username;
        $this->setState('lastLogin', date("m/d/y g:i A", strtotime($user->last_login_time)));
        $user->saveAttributes(array('last_login_time'=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s", time())));
        $this->errorCode=self::ERROR_NONE;
    }
    return $this->errorCode==self::ERROR_NONE;
}
public function getId()
{
    return $this->_id;
}
```

and then i get this

```
Property "CWebUser.depId" is not defined.
```

what is the problem here ?!

Comment: Is the user authenticated when you call `Yii::app()->user->depId`, and is dep_id the right column name?

Comment: Agreed with @veelen presumably if dep_id is the column name you shoudl be using `Yii::app()->user->dep_id`

Comment: How to get sure that the user is authenticated ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to be authenticated user to use that variable on above scenario because it is restricted for authenticated users.

Comment: and how to make that possible ?!

Comment: I think you know what is authenticated users, because you are writing just above code to authenticate the users. Your application users will be authenticated just after they login with valid credentials required to web application.